# How to pull temperature info out off Open Weather Map API

Tags: javascript, api, temperature, weather-api

Hi I have been given this code and I am trying to build upon it.

I am using Open Weather Map API. At the moment I am just finding out what the weather is.

But I want to also find out the temperature and also display it!

```
function getLocation() {
    var location = document.getElementById("location").value;
    location = location.replace(" ", "%20");

    if (location == "") {
        document.getElementById("location").classList.add("error");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("location").classList.remove("error");
        getWeather(location);
    }
}

function getWeather(location) {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var json;
    var apiKEY = "****dd982d18c618";
    var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + location + " ,uk&appid=" + apiKEY;

    ajax.open("GET", url, true);
    ajax.send();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            json = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
            document.getElementById("locationForm").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("weather").style.display = "block";
            if (json != undefined) {
                var weather = json.weather[0].main
                setIconAndDescription(weather, location)
            } else {
                description = "Oops, I couldn't find the weather in " + location;
                document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = description;
            }
        }
    }
}

function setIconAndDescription(weather, location) {
    var icon;
    var description;
    weather = weather.toLowerCase();

    if (weather == "clear sky" || weather == "clear") {
        icon = "clear.svg";
        description = "Yay, sunshine!";
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FA6144";
        document.getElementById("icon").style.backgroundColor = "#7A2F21";
        document.getElementById("temp").style.backgroundColor = "#7A2F21";
        document.getElementById("description").style.backgroundColor = "#E0563D";
    } else if (weather == "few clouds") {
        icon = "few-clouds.svg";
        description = "It's a little cloudy.";
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FA6144";
        document.getElementById("icon").style.backgroundColor = "#7A2F21";
        document.getElementById("temp").style.backgroundColor = "#7A2F21";
        document.getElementById("description").style.backgroundColor = "#E0563D";
    } else if (weather == "scattered clouds" || weather == "broken clouds" || weather == "clouds") {
        icon = "clouds.svg";
        description = "Looks like scattered clouds today.";
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FA6144";
        document.getElementById("icon").style.backgroundColor = "#7A2F21";
        document.getElementById("temp").style.backgroundColor = "#7A2F21";
        document.getElementById("description").style.backgroundColor = "#E0563D";
    } else if (weather == "rain" || weather == "light rain" || weather == "shower rain") {
        icon = "rain.svg";
        description = "Looks like rain."
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FA6144";
        document.getElementById("icon").style.backgroundColor = "#7A2F21";
        document.getElementById("temp").style.backgroundColor = "#7A2F21";
        document.getElementById("description").style.backgroundColor = "#E0563D";
    } else if (weather == "thunderstorm") {
        icon = "thunder.svg";
        description = "Yikes, looks like a storm's brewing!"
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = ",";
        document.getElementById("icon").style.backgroundColor = "#7A2F21";
        document.getElementById("temp").style.backgroundColor = "#7A2F21";
        document.getElementById("description").style.backgroundColor = "#E0563D";
    } else if (weather == "snow") {
        icon = "snow.svg";
        description = "Wrap up, it's going to snow!"
    } else if (weather == "mist") {
        icon = "mist.svg";
        description = "Looks a little misty today.";
    } else {
        icon = "default.svg";
        description = "Oops, I couldn't find the weather in " + location;
    }

    document.getElementById("weatherIcon").src = "images/" + icon;
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = description;
}

(function () {
    document.getElementById("btnGo").onclick = getLocation;
    document.getElementById("location").onkeypress = function (key) {
        if (key.keyCode == "13") {
            getLocation();
        }
    };
    //   //Convert temp from kelvin to celsius:
    //   var tempCelsius = Math.round(((data.main.temp) - 273.15));
    //
    //   $("#temp").html(tempCelsius + "C");
    //
    // });
})();
```

The bottom is what I have come up with by searching and trying to figure out how other people have done it.

```
//Convert temp from kelvin to celsius:
            //   var tempCelsius = Math.round(((data.main.temp) - 273.15));
                //
            //   $("#temp").html(tempCelsius + "C");
                //
            // });
```

With this it so far it doesn't work. I have tried other versions that allow the rest of the date too work. Though doing it this way the data do not show in the assigned div.

Having a last look at it. I feel like it might need to be inside a function?

Any help would be great,

thanks,

Zack

***Edit***

This is what I have done but it is still not working. Does there need to be a function for it to work?

As the first line sets "temperature" as the data from the json.

Then the second line does the conversion.

Then the third puts it all together. I hope inside the div "temp"

```
    // var temperature = json.main.temp;
        //
      //     temperature = Math.round(((data.main.temp) - 273.15));
        //
      //     $("#temp").html(temperature + "C");
        //
      //   });
})();
```

Should I be console logging it instead?

thanks,

Zack

Comment: You probably don't want to broadcast your API key to the planet here.

Comment: Start by console.log(json.weather)

Comment: The [response contains all you need](http://openweathermap.org/current#current_JSON) -> `var temperature = json.main.temp;`

Comment: @PaulAbbott Yea forgot about that good catch, thanks :)

Comment: @mplungjan Hummm so console log you say... Do I just add that into my code and it will print all the data from the api out? So I will need to change it so it only console logs the temp.. console.log(json.weather.main.temp).

Comment: @mplungjan I feel like this is too easy though

Comment: @Andreas I have add what I think you are saying for me to do above. I must not be getting the hint as it is still not working.

Comment: console.log is to see how the data looks like. If json.main.temp holds it, then that is what you can use. What does not work in your last code?

Comment: It looks like this is a duplicate of your question you asked before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426090/how-to-use-this-api-to-return-the-temperature-with-javascript. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of christmas... :)

Replace the function

```
function setIconAndDescription(weather, location) {
    // ...
}
```

with this one

```
function showWeatherInfo(weatherInfo) {
    var weather = weatherInfo.weather[0].main.toLowerCase(),
        temperature = weatherInfo.main.temp;

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FA6144";
    document.getElementById("icon").style.backgroundColor = "#7A2F21";
    document.getElementById("temp").style.backgroundColor = "#7A2F21";
    document.getElementById("description").style.backgroundColor = "#E0563D";

    if (weather == "clear sky" || weather == "clear") {
        icon = "clear.svg";
        description = "Yay, sunshine!";
    } else if (weather == "few clouds") {
        icon = "few-clouds.svg";
        description = "It's a little cloudy.";
    } else if (weather == "scattered clouds" || weather == "broken clouds" || weather == "clouds") {
        icon = "clouds.svg";
        description = "Looks like scattered clouds today.";
    } else if (weather == "rain" || weather == "light rain" || weather == "shower rain") {
        icon = "rain.svg";
        description = "Looks like rain."
    } else if (weather == "thunderstorm") {
        icon = "thunder.svg";
        description = "Yikes, looks like a storm's brewing!"
    } else if (weather == "snow") {
        icon = "snow.svg";
        description = "Wrap up, it's going to snow!"
    } else if (weather == "mist") {
        icon = "mist.svg";
        description = "Looks a little misty today.";
    } else {
        icon = "default.svg";
        description = "Oops, I couldn't find the weather in " + location;
    }

    document.getElementById("weatherIcon").src = "images/" + icon;
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = description;
    document.getElementById("temp").textContent = temperature + " K"; /*kelvin, for celsius: (temperature - 273.15) + " °C"*/
}
```

The last line is for the temperature.
(I've also restructured the code a little bit)

Then replace this `if` block in the `onreadystatechange` handler

```
if (json != undefined) {
    var weather = json.weather[0].main
    setIconAndDescription(weather, location)
}
```

with this

```
if (json != undefined) {
    showWeatherInfo(json)
}
```

to call the new function passing in the complete weather info from openweathermap.

Comment: Your welcome :-) Merry Christmas and some relaxing holidays for you and your family!